# Can't open text file when running a javascript file as a systemd service

Tags: javascript, node.js, systemd

I'm running a **javascript** file from **node** on my **raspberry pi** on startup automatically by using **systemd** service.

I loosely followed [this guide](https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/nodejs-service-with-systemd/) to do the above.

When I run my javascript file manually using the command: Node Cloversale.js

it runs fine, and reads from my files as expected.

However, when running it as a service I get the following errors:

```
Feb 12 17:48:19 sensohub systemd[1]: Started Clover Service.
Feb 12 17:48:24 sensohub node[8640]: 2018-02-12 17:48:24.028 INFO  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'token.txt'
Feb 12 17:48:24 sensohub node[8640]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'token.txt'
Feb 12 17:48:24 sensohub node[8640]: at Error (native)
Feb 12 17:48:24 sensohub node[8640]: 2018-02-12 17:48:24.068 INFO  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'endpoint.txt'
Feb 12 17:48:24 sensohub node[8640]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'endpoint.txt'
Feb 12 17:48:24 sensohub node[8640]: at Error (native)
Feb 12 17:48:24 sensohub node[8640]: 2018-02-12 17:48:24.117 INFO  Connected to OCR-Pi Server
```

I tried using chmod 644 on my services file, so I don't think its a permissions issue, but thats what other sites I've read seem to indicate.

Here is my clover.services file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Clover Service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/pi/OCR-Pi/NSR/cloversale.js 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

Right after posting this I figured it out... Apparently I had to give read and write permissions to both the Javascript file **and** the .service file.

so typing `chmod 644 cloversale.js` fixed the issue.